# Android/Java - pause thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to this, so maybe it's trivial to everybody, but I just can't figure out, why this isn't working. I've read about it, tried many way, and still not working. So I want to pause a thread in android (java). I want this to run, freeze the screen for 1 sec, and continue working. That's all. Why isn't this working?

```
public class Game extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

        runner.join();
        runner.start();

        // do stuff

        pause();

        // do stuff


}

private boolean running = true;
private boolean paused = false;

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    running = run;
}

public void pause() {
    paused = true;
}

Thread runner = new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        while (running) {

            try {

                //do stuff

                Thread.sleep(100);

                while (paused) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                        paused = false;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }

};
```

}

Comment: Your exception in the `while(paused)` loop may be triggering. Log the exception's message to the console in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order of the methods call, you coded:

```
    runner.join();
    runner.start();
```

Change to:

```
runner.start();
runner.join();
```

And it should work.

Comment: This way all I can see is black screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid spinning try this:

```
private boolean isPaused = false;


public synchronized void pause(){
    isPaused = true;
}

public synchronized void play(){
   isPaused = false;
   notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void look(){
   while(isPaused)
      wait();
}

 public void run(){
     while(true){
        look();
        //your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `Thread.sleep` in the `onCreate` method. Throw out all the thread stuff. It is just wrong.

Why at all you want to freeze the screen? This is a very bad approach. Use Dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you need freeze screen, you only need use ***SystemClock.sleep(millis)***.//1000 = 1 second
Android use a main thread for your interface very different . Your code try stop it like a java program.

Example

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
```

...

or search info like this:

```
//this is similar to your thread
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //some code
           int val = 1+ 1; //code here dont interrupt main thread

           //this code run on main thread
           mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   //freeze Views
                   SystemClock.sleep(1000);// 1 second
               }
           });

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

delayprg(3000);//3seg

```
 private void delayprg(int delayc) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayc);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```