# How to signal a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Process running which creates a Thread object and runs it. Now based on some events in Process, I want Thread to react accordingly. More precisely if commonVar becomes true, then thread B should pause in while loop. Then when commonVar becomes false, then thread B should start from beginning of run() method.

Note that the thread B doesn't write to commonVar. It just reads it.

```
public class B implements runnable
{
    Boolean commanVar;

    public B(boolean commanVar) {
        this.commonVar = commonVar;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true) {
        // do some processing
        }
    }
}

public class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean commonVar = false;
        Thread threadB = new Thread(new ClassB(commonVar));
        threadB.start();
        // some processing will happen and because of that commonVar will change.
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android/Java - pause thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794684/android-java-pause-thread)

Comment: Only way to get what you want is for thread B to periodically check the value of the flag, and pause itself (e.g., by waiting on a condition variable) when appropriate. If you need thread B to _instantly_ stop whatever it happens to be doing at the exact moment when the flag is set, then sorry to say, you're going to need a different architecture, because Java threads don't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not stop threads. Instead, issue tasks (via BlockingQueue) or signals (by Semaphore), and let them run while they have input, and hang when input is exhausted.